# Recover Magento Static Block content from backup?

Tags: mysql, xml, magento, php

I had major problems with my work in progress Magento site so decided to start again from scratch. I thought I'd made copies of everything I would re-add in the fresh install but I forgot about a couple of static blocks.

I have recreated the static blocks but wondered if the content that I added (HTML & text) to the static block is retrievable from the file system backup I took before I re-installed?

I've had a look through the file system but can't seem to see where this would be stored.

I have a database backup also but don't want to restore it due to the problems I had prior to the re-install.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to retrieve the static block content from my backup and if so, how/where?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all CMS Page and Block content is stored in the database and fairly easily retrievable via a text editor. I've had to do it before.

View the following tables in phpMyAdmin to get an idea of the structure and column content:

- CMS Blocks are stored in `cms_block`
- CMS Pages are stored in `cms_page`

Display code for both is found in the `content` column, CMS Page layout is found in in the `layout_update_xml` and `custom_layout_update_xml` columns.

Have a look at the other columns to decide what else you need to extract.

Now, using 7-zip if on Windows, or native command line tools, uncompress your database dump and use a programming text editor that can handle large text files like **TextPad** to search for your content. Look for the table name (in this case, `cms_block`).

There will be two SQL code sections (similar to sample below), the first builds the `cms_block` table, the second adds the content.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `cms_block`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cms_block`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `cms_block` (
  `block_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `identifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` mediumtext,
  `creation_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`block_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='CMS Blocks';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cms_block`
--

LOCK TABLES `cms_block` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cms_block` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `cms_block` VALUES (LongUglyContentStringHere);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cms_block` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

We're interested in the `INSERT INTO`cms_block`VALUES` line which will be so long that your text editor probably cannot assimilate it. Cut that line, paste it into a second document, turn on word wrap and search for the `identifier` or some unique content that was in the block. Records in this block are surrounded by parenthesis and comma separated `(recordx),(recordy),(recordz)`.

In the sample, we want to recover `price-match` and here's the record contained in parenthesis:

```
(40,'Price Match','price-match','<!-- Price Match Offer Text for price-match submission form -->\r\n<h3>We Will Match or Beat Any Competitors Price</h3>\r\n<p>If you find a better price for an item from \r\nanother authorized dealer, We will do everything possible to match or beat that price. Price adjustments are applicable \r\nto identical items only. The item must be new and product lead times may vary. You will find the \"Price Match\" tab on each \r\nproduct page with a submission form for price adjustments.</p>','2012-01-27 06:11:04','2012-01-31 05:28:16',1)
```

Use what you gleaned from phpMyAdmin as to the column order and contents to help recover, but it's basically `block_id, title, identifier, content` and surrounded with parenthesis with single quote string boundaries and comma separators.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, you've saved me hours of work! I downloaded a plugin for excel in the end and opened the sql file that way and then found the blocks in question.

Comment: You're welcome! Everything stored in the database is accessible in this fashion, even resurrecting month's old accidentally deleted product from ancient db backups. Do you have a name for that Excel extension? Sounds like a very useful tool.

Comment: Yeah it's called SQL Drill :)

Comment: Hey, thanks! Any useful weapon to kill the Magento monsters appreciated!